# Informe consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, select, tablas

Tengo la siguientes tablas;

Pedido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cliente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es sacar un informe como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la medida que más clientes hagan pedidos, se vayan agregando en una columna del informe.

Estoy usando UNION ALL para la consulta pero el resultado no es el esperado ya que me coloca en forma de fila:

```
select producto from pedido where id_cliente = 1 UNION ALL select producto from pedido where id_cliente = 4;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Realmente quieres que la base de datos haga eso,o quieres mostrar eso en unn html? porque puedes consultar clientes y productos por aparte y mostrar los datos en un html de la forma que quieres. es tu objetivo?

Comment: @CristianCamilo Hola, de antemano gracias por tu comentario. Realmente quiero sacarlo por consulta. Normalmente se hace en la vista, en html por ejemplo, pero quiero saber si hay alguna forma de sacar un informe así por consulta SQL. Gracias.